# Is it possible to set breakpoint condition as "break when called by another thread"?

Tags: windows, multithreading, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm investigating an issue that might be caused by multithread. The data is constantly being read by a thread, I'd like to see if it is being read by another thread.

I can set breakpoint and keep pressing F5 and check if it is breaking in the other thread, but it's a little annoying. Is it possible to set breakpoint condition as "break when called by another thread"?

Comment: Use assert() instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up a *Filter* (see [Using Breakpoints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx)). The filter can be set on *ThreadId*, for example. To set a filter, right-click a breakpoint, select *Conditions...*, and enter

```
ThreadId!=<thread ID you aren't interested in>
```

as the filter expression. Make sure there aren't any whitespace characters in the expression. Otherwise you will be greeted with a not-so-helpful error message.

Comment: Thanks, it is quite useful, I even tried `!(ThreadID=113772) & !(ThreadID=99337)` and it works :)